# How to simply use docker for deployment?

Tags: docker

Docker seems to be the incredible new tool to solve all developer headaches when it comes to packaging and releasing an application, yet i'm unable to find simple solutions for just upgrading a existing application without having to build or buy into whole "cloud" systems.

I don't want any kubernetes cluster or docker-swarm to deploy hundreds of microservices. Just simply replace an existing deployment process with a container for better encapsulation and upgradability.
Then maybe upgrade this in the future, if the need for more containers increases so manual handling would not make sense anymore

Essentially the direct app dependencies (Language and Runtime, dependencies) should be bundled up without the need to "litter" the host server with them.
Lower level static services, like the database, should still be in the host system, as well as a entry router/load-balancer (simple nginx proxy).

Does it even make sense to use it this way? And if so, is there any "best practice" for doing something like this?

Update:

For the application i want to use it on, i'm already using Gitlab-CI.
Tests are already run inside a docker environment via Gitlab-CI, but deployment still happens the "old way" (syncing the git repo to the server and automatically restarting the app, etc).

Containerizing the application itself is not an issue, and i've also used full docker deployments via cloud services (mostly Heroku), but for this project something like this is overkill. No point in paying hundreds of $$ for a cloud server environment if i need pretty much none of the advantages of it.
I've found several of "install your own heroku" kind of systems but i don't need or want to manage the complexity of a dynamic system.

I suppose basically a couple of remote bash commands for updating and restarting a docker container (after it's been pushed to a registry by the CI) on the server, could already do the job - though probably pretty unreliably compared to the current way.

Comment: Did you take a look to docker documentation ? https://docs.docker.com/

Comment: Been reading dozens of different how tos and looking through the docker docs as well.
I could probably piece together a working hello-world-ish solution, still not sure if that would be a recommended way or i'm better of following a proven pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the "best practice" is highly subjective, as it depends entirely on your setup and your organization.

It seems like you're looking for an extremely minimalist approach to Docker containers. You want to simply put source code and dependencies into a container and push that out to a system. This is definitely possible with Docker, but the manner of doing this is going to require research from you to see what fits best.

Here are the questions I think you should be asking to get started:

1) Is there a CI tool that will help me package together these containers, possibly something I'm already using? (Jenkins, GitLab CI, CircleCI, TravisCI, etc...)

2) Can I use the official Docker images available at Dockerhub (https://hub.docker.com/), or do I need to make my own?

3) How am I going to store Docker Images? Will I host a basic Docker registry (https://hub.docker.com/_/registry/), or do I want something with a bit more access control (Gitlab Container Registry, Harbor, etc...)

That really only focuses on the Continuous Integration part of your question. Once you figure this out, then you can start to think about how you want to deploy those images (Possibly even using one of the tools above).

Note: Also, Docker doesn't eliminate all developer headaches. Does it solve some of the problems? Absolutely. But what Docker, and the accompanying Container mindset, does best is shift many of those issues to the left. What this means is that you see many of the problems in your processes early, instead of those problems appearing when you're pushing to prod and you suddenly have a fire drill. Again, Docker should not be seen as a solve-all. If you go into Docker thinking it will be a solve-all, then you're setting yourself up for failure.

Comment: Thank you for the details write up. I updated my question above.
Essentially i already have all the pieces in place to use docker (Gitlab-CI already using it to prepare the application) and just really need the last part of how i reliably deploy the finished image onto a basic static server.

Comment: @maxigs Thanks for the update. One thing I'm still curious on is your answer to #3 in the questions I listed above. In your GitLab CI process, you mention tests, but are you also creating an executable docker image of the application? If so, are you storing that image in a registry somewhere?

Comment: currently there is only a transient docker build for the gitlab-ci step (using the docker runner).
I have setup up everything i need to build the actual docker image, and did already use the same progress to push them to heroku. Also i'm using docker-hub for my base images (the ones used by gitlab-ci, as well as building).
But heroku/aws/etc are way overpriced (about 10x or more than i currently pay!) for a project where i just need one cheap bare box, no fast scalability or other cloud features, otherwise i would use it.